# Using assembly redirection in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

**Hi!**

I'm getting a typeload exception, the assembly being loaded is targeting runtime version v2.0.50727, other assemblies targets v4.0.30319.
I've been reading about Assembly Redirection and I think it could solve this problem but I'm unsure how this would be applied in a UWP app as there is no app.config.
Any advice would be helpful!

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket' from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.'
```

Comment: UWP does sockets differently, you cannot use the Socket class.  Look at StreamSocket to get ahead.

Comment: We don't have access to the source of the library we are referencing, not sure how we would solve that then, maybe run it as a service or something. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Could you tell me your uwp app target version and min version? And could you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I have made a solution that reproduces the error but I can't include the library, it's part of a payment solution. 
I could try and create a new library that produces the same error.  
Target version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)  
Min version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)

Comment: @PhilipJernås I am trying to reproduce this issue in my side to try to see why it happens. Could you tell me the steps how can I reproduce it?so that I can look into the issue?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I wrote a similar library that uses sockets and .Net 3.5
https://github.com/Nesox/UWPSocketError
It should fail when it tries to load the IPAddress type, it's the same exception we are getting but with another type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP platform, it would be better to create a Universal Windows Class Library then add it as a reference into the UWP project. You can try to create a Universal Windows Class Library and add your code into it as the following image,

[image]

From Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(16299), UWP supports .Net Standard 2.0, you can also create a .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library in VS2017.

Last but not least, I think you should learn more about the relationship among .Net Framework, .Net standard and UWP, you can look into the following blogs to get a better understanding:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814993.aspx

Comment: Thanks,we decided to use a WCF service to wrap the library in instead, we started writing our own socket server/client but WCF is a lot easier to work with and UWP supports it.  I will read those links, thanks for your time